# How to write a mark_as_deleted method in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to write a method which should work like the destroy method in any Rails default controller but shouldn’t really delete the data. Rather it should set a flag or something which I can evaluate in my views to not show this data any more.

So when the user clicks on ’Delete’ the corresponding action should mark the data as deleted but not purge the data from my database.

What’s the most elegant way of writing such a method? I’m using Rails 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to do is show or hide data I would have a boolean `is_visible` field in the database.

Also, rather than evaluating in your view whether or not to show this data I'd put that logic in the model, in a `default_scope` (available in rails 3). So something like this (assuming you want to show/hide `Articles`)...

```
# model
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(:is_visible => true)
end
```

Obviously, your delete method should just set the `is_visible` boolean to `false` and on creation it should default to `true`.

Then you just need to be careful if your data has relations to other data. In this example, if you have `Articles` and they have `Comments` then maybe you don't want the `Comments` to show up anywhere if an `Article` is marked as not visible.

Comment: The scope has to be in the model, not in the controller. But it works perfectly like this :-). Thanks.

Comment: oops, yeah model not controller!

Answer (score 3):

In some of my apps, I have added a column onto content types called `status`, which can be either "posted", "draft", or "removed". This way, users can make drafts or remove posted items without messing up the index views.

As far as elegance, it might not be the best, but I just create a `new_draft` method on the content types, which creates a new object with `status` set to "draft". Then, when the user posts their draft, I call a `post` method which sets `status` to "posted". Once posted, if a user removes their item, I call a `remove` method which (you guessed it!) sets `status` to "removed".